# Angular9 ReactiveForm returns null value on Submit

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular9

I'm just getting nuts. I tried to build a simple login form with username and password. I used the Reactive Forms approach from Angular and I always get null values returned when submitting the form. The form state always shows invalid. It looks like I'm getting another instance of a form but not the form I expect from the submit. Could please someone help me?

This is my module file:

```
@NgModule({
 imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ContentPagesRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
 ],
 declarations: [
    ComingSoonPageComponent,
    ErrorPageComponent,
    ForgotPasswordPageComponent,
    LockScreenPageComponent,
    LoginPageComponent,
    MaintenancePageComponent,
    RegisterPageComponent
 ],
 providers: [
  FormBuilder
 ]
})
```

This is my component file:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-page',
  templateUrl: './login-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-page.component.scss']
})
export class LoginPageComponent {
  loginForm: FormGroup;
  model: any = {};

  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) 
  {
  }

  get lf() { return this.loginForm.controls; }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: new FormControl({value: 'jimmy', disabled: false}, [Validators.required]),
      password: new FormControl('123456', [Validators.required])
    });
  }

  // On submit button click
  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.loginForm);
    this.loginForm.reset();
  }

  // On Forgot password link click
  onForgotPassword() {
    this.router.navigate(['forgotpassword'], { relativeTo: this.route.parent });
  }

  // On registration link click
  onRegister() {
    this.router.navigate(['register'], { relativeTo: this.route.parent });
  }
}
```

And this the HTML File where the form is located:

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <!--BEGIN FORM INPUT-->
    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" placeholder="Username" formControlName="username"/>
    <input type="password" class="form-control mb-3" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password"/>
    <!--END FORM INPUT-->

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mt-2">
        <div class="remember-me">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline mb-3" >
                <input type="checkbox" id="customCheckboxInline1" name="customCheckboxInline1" class="custom-control-input" />
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheckboxInline1">
                Remember Me
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="forgot-password-option">
            <a [routerLink]="['/pages/forgotpassword']" class="text-decoration-none text-primary">Forgot Password ?</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="fg-actions d-flex justify-content-between">
        <div class="login-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                <a [routerLink]="['/pages/register']" class="text-decoration-none" >Register</a>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="recover-pass">
            <button [disabled]="!loginForm.valid" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                <span class="text-decoration-none text-white">Login</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

[Form output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTcsc.png)

Maybe there is someone who gets what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz ?

Comment: When load the page do you see values on your inputs,jimmy and 123456?

Comment: You are mixing manual setting up of the form (new FormControl) with formbuilder, which is not correct. If you use formbuilder.group, you shouldn’t use new Formcontrol. Check the syntax.

Comment: jeah i see the inputy, if i print the values on the page with {{loginForm.value | json }} i get every value from the form and every change shows immediatly up...if i submit the form i got null values.

Comment: @JimmyPage Look my answer. I added a working example of your form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove

```
(ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"
```

Add on your submit button

```
(click)="onSubmit()"
```

**[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-4mrvqe)**

Comment: if i try it like you mentioned above i get a syntax error.

Comment: @JimmyPage Check my working example. i kept your formControls

Comment: @JimmyPage https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-4mrvqe

Comment: in your working Example you are using:
 new FormControl('123456', [Validators.required]).
I tried it with your code above but i get the same result...i don't get something is completly wrong but i don't get it

Comment: Did you remove (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"? You can leave your formControls as you have it. Remove  this.loginForm.reset(); now for the test

Comment: i removed this.loginForm.reset(); and it just startet working. thank you for you help. Now i have to find out how the Form could get resetted without killing my values ^^ :)

Comment: Great! On my example i added this.loginForm.reset(); onsubmit method but it works properly. First console my data and after reset my form

Comment: i've had the this.loginForm.reset(); after the console.log(this.loginForm); in the onSubmit() but it killed my values. I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

MikeOne if i change it to this:

```
 this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    username: ['jimmy', [Validators.required]],
    password: ['123456', [Validators.required]]
  });
```

i get the same result.